# Помогите создать скрипт медленного исчезновения изображения

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, pillow

Нужно написать скрипт,который с течением какого-то времени,уменьшал прозрачность изображения.Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно помочь создать или создать самим? Если первое, то что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: @vp_arth,Второе:)

Comment: Дело в том, что tkinter это лишь интерфейс к Tk. Насколько я знаю, в Tk такой готовой функциональности нет. Потом, Tk использует X11, а под Windows, например, эмулирует его, чтобы пользоваться одним и тем же интерфейсом. X11 плохо справляется с такими задачами. Вот здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363491/how-to-make-transparent-window-on-linux рекомендуют использовать OpenGL. То есть для решения вашей задачи "нормально" нужно писать свой виджет для Tk. Это делается на C и довольно нетривиально с первого раза. Либо искать готовый виджет. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что такого не будет.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov,спасибо вам большое !

Comment: @Danil-py, попробуйте погуглить по запросу "tkinter opengl". Но если вы даже не попытались написать скрипт, то это все равно будет сложно, такие дела.

Comment: pillow содержит Image, с помощью которого вы сможете загрузить файл
и ImageTk, для того, чтобы создать из полученного изображение, пригодное для выкладывания на Canvas (например).

Останется только разобраться, как можно изменить прозрачность. Возможно putalpha - это то, что нужно.